# C: close FILE* - not filedescriptor

Tags: c, fdopen

I wondered if it was possible to release a `FILE` wrapper, without closing the underlying file descriptor:

```
void stream_function( int fd ) {
    FILE * stream = fdopen( fd, "r");
    // Read from stream with fread / fscanf
    // then close the buffered stream object with the mythical
    // xclose( stream ) function, leaving the fd intact. 
    xclose( stream );  
}


int main( ) {
   int fd = open("filename" , flags);
   stream_function( fd );
   // Continue to use fd
   close( fd );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not. You can use `dup2(fileno(f))` to keep a copy of the file descriptor, but `fclose(f)` inherently and always closes `fileno(f)`.

In cases like yours where you're using `fdopen` to get the `FILE *` to begin with, however, you can `dup2` the fd before passing it to `fdopen`. This protects the original fd from being closed at `fclose` time.